# Need to change username in aws code commit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I want to change my current username in AWS code commit. How do I do that?

I try my luck with aws docs but nothing helpful there for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

what exactly do you mean by "change my current username"? If you talking about the user which appears as an author in your git commits then this has nothing to do with CodeCommit in general, but can be changed through your local git settings via [`git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"`](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Code Commit users are IAM users so you will need to change your IAM user name follwing this guide

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_manage.html#id_users_renaming